# Ruby: Iterate the result from method using block

Tags: ruby

Now I have a ruby like this:

```html
def fizzbuzz(numSize)
    result = []
    1.upto(numSize) do |num|
        if num % 15 == 0
            result << "FizzBuzz"
        elsif num % 3 == 0
            result << "Fizz"
        elsif num % 5 == 0
            result << "Buzz"
        else
            result << num.to_s
        end
    end
    result
end

print fizzbuzz(10) {|item| "-#{i1tem}-"}
```

If I want to print the result like this:
["-1-", "-2-", "-Fizz-", "-4-", "-Buzz-", "-Fizz-", "-7-", "-8-", "-Fizz-", "-Buzz-"]

What can I modify my code in method fizzbuzz if I can not change the code:

```html
print fizzbuzz(10) {|item| "-#{i1tem}-"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: OK I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That block is being given to your method, but you're not making use of it. That's an easy fix:

```rb
def fizzbuzz(numSize, &block)
  # ... (existing code) ...
  result.map(&block)
end
```

Where that transforms the result value using `map`.

Note this requires fixing the typo in your `print` block which is `i1tem` not `item`.

It's also worth noting you should avoid this pattern:

```
x = [ ]
y.each do |v|
  x << f(v)
end
x
```

That's just a long-winded version of this:

```
y.map do |v|
  f(v)
end
```

Where when you're *transforming* on a 1:1 basis from the source just use `map`.

In your case that reduces the code to this more minimal form that has a lot less repetition:

```rb
def fizzbuzz(numSize, &block)
  1.upto(numSize).map do |num|
    if num % 15 == 0
      "FizzBuzz"
    elsif num % 3 == 0
      "Fizz"
    elsif num % 5 == 0
      "Buzz"
    else
      num.to_s
    end
  end.map(&block)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I change your code using block if I want both of the result like
 ["1", "2"]  if I call fizzbuzz(2) and ["-1-", "-2-"]  if I call   fizzbuzz(2) {|item| "-#{item}-"}

Comment: Then you need a conditional map at the end. Wrap that in an `if (block_given?)`.